# Using predicted variable among interaction predictors in R

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients

I'm trying to build a model in order to predict a certain variable using the following model:

```
lm(formula = Var.y ~ Var.x + IntraDayVary + Var.y:IntraDayVary + VarVolume + 0, data = merged)
```

Although the metrics from the resulting model are quite promising, I'm dubious that the use of the predicted variable as part of an interaction predictor (Var.y:IntradayVary) is conceptually sound.

I'm wondering what R will actually do with the model when using the predict function. Will it calculate the interaction between the real Var.y and IntradayVary or will it be between the predicted Var.y and IntradayVary?

Thanks!

Comment: What will *you* actually do with a model that requires you to know already the value of something you're trying to predict?

Comment: Stock movements. I want to model the relationship between variation in one asset with another, obviously trying to predict an outcome.

Comment: The predicted outcome of your model is `Var.y`; the inputs to your model include `Var.y`: so you can only predict `Var.y` when you already know it. (Why not just use `Var.y ~ Var.y` ?) I suggest you take a step back & explain the problem you're trying to solve & why this model seems appropriate - there may be some non-linear or time series formulation that is what you really want.

Comment: Long story short, I wanna model the relationship between an index and an asset, with the parameters enumerated above. For now, I do have `Var.y`, but I plan on using the model on fresh data where it won't be available.

Comment: I tried using the predict() function on a test dataset where I removed `Var.y` and it worked flawlessly, leading me to believe that the interaction coefficient is used with the predicted `Var.y` rather than the actual.

Thanks a lot for your help btw.